# ember.js attribute binding and the event object

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

So far, it looks like Ember does not work as I expected, and I'm hoping I've just missed something.  What I need to do is iterate over my model, a blob of JSON made up of arrays and objects, and build out a form.  When the user marks a checkbox, the controllers Action updates the model.

Here's how I want it to work...

```
  <form {{action 'answerSupplied'}}>
    {{#each model.questions}}
      <h3>{{text}}</h3>

        {{#each answers}}
            {{input type='../type' answerId='id' data-bind-questionNum='../id' text}}
        {{/each}}

    {{/each}}
  </form>
```

Here's how I can get close to that...

```
  <form {{action 'answerSupplied' this}}>
    {{#each model.questions}}
      <h3>{{text}}</h3>

        {{#each answers}}
            {{formbuilder ../type id ../id text}}
        {{/each}}

    {{/each}}
  </form>
==================
Handlebars.registerHelper('formbuilder', function(type, id, qnum, text, options)
{
//    console.log(options);

    var q_type = options.contexts[0][type],
        a_id = options.contexts[1].id,
        q_number = options.contexts[0][qnum],
        a_text = options.contexts[1].text;

        return new Handlebars.SafeString(
                '<input type='+ q_type +' id='+ a_id +' name='+
                    q_number +'>'+ a_text + '</input><br/>'
        );
    }
});
```

The big problem wit this is,  I can not identify which element was clicked because  I don't have access to the event object.

Can I manually bind the action with something like 'data-ember-action', and pass in params?  Or, is this too far outside the Ember way?

== update ==

Here's the above [JSFiddle](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xoqoh/1/edit), improved by passing parameters to the Action. The event propagation seems to get halted in the Action resulting in the inputs not getting properly marked.  Radio buttons loose their grouping, and checkboxes do not get checked.

Answer (score 2):

Ember can easily handle what you're doing here. First it's easier to keep your scope and generate named each loops.

```
 <form {{action 'answerSupplied'}}>
    {{#each question in model.questions}}
      <h3>{{question.text}}</h3>

        {{#each answer in question.answers}}
            {{input type=question.type answerId=answer.id data-bind-questionNum=question.id placeHolder=answer.text}}
        {{/each}}

    {{/each}}
  </form>
```

You may have to do some if statements for labels etc around your input statements.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zofoqeje/1/edit

Comment: Thanks.  That helps a lot.  I figured it should work this way.  I won't be able to test until after work, but it looks like the data-bind attributes are meant to be passed to the Action? If that works, I'll be super happy with Ember.

Comment: I was able to get even closer and pass in parameters with this code in the named 'each' loops:     `<input {{bind-attr type="question.type" name="question.index" questionNum="question.id" answerId="answer.id"}} {{action 'answerSupplied' answer.id question.id this}}>{{answer.text}} </input><br/>`  ...but, the event gets trapped in the controller and the checkboxes and radio buttons do not get marked.  How can I let the event continue its bubbling and check the checkboxes?